# What questions should be deleted?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

The relevant [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) page says:

> Closed questions that are of *no lasting value whatsoever* should be
>   flagged and deleted.

On the other hand, the [Deleted Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) section of the FAQ says:

> Questions that are *extremely off topic, or of very low quality*, may be
>   removed at the discretion of the community and moderators.

Neither explanation is very detailed. The second definition clearly allows more leeway, but, at least to me, it doesn't match very well with the first one.

There are some cases where the rules clearly apply, such as recent questions quickly closed as "too broad" or "unclear" and with no answers.

But is a clearly off-topic question like a "request for tools" (for which there are *many* old, highly-voted examples) of no value *whatsoever*? Some of those are pretty high in the "Most Delete Votes" section, but I'm really puzzled about whether they are legitimate targets for deletion, and why those particular ones were targeted, when a great many similar ones are not.

Not complaining about any question in particular, just looking for some input on this.

Answer (score 2):

> But is a clearly off-topic question like a "request for tools" (for which there are many old, highly-voted examples) of no value whatsoever?

Yes, questions like that are of no value. Due to the changing nature of the site these antecedents should not be used as precedents. You will find that most of the "old highly voted examples" have also been closed and deleted, some of them survive with a [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/146015).

If you are concerned about casting a delete vote on a closed question, remember that [closed negatively scored questions older than 30 days with no answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/146015) will be automatically culled. If a question is closed very quickly, is starting to accrue negative votes and has little potential to be reopened then it's best to delete it.

If it is simply the definitions that you are concerned about then you could suggest new phrasing. IMVHO though it is best to leave it unspecific (like the first one you listed), after you have been hanging around for a while you will get a feel for which questions need deleting - to try and document this exactly will be a futile exercise.

Comment: Thanks. As a corollary, I understand that it's also OK to vote to delete the "old highly voted examples" themselves -- so long as they do not have such a lock, upvotes be damned?

Comment: @matiash That's correct - if they're closed then they are also candidates for deletion, although I can't recall if the number of delete votes required is related to the number of up votes. Those questions were good and popular once upon a time, but times have changed :)

Comment: I'll go ahead and mention it -- because I strongly feel like visitors feel the same way but I don't think request for tools questions should be closed. Contrary to the site rules these types of questions are incredibly popular and it'd be a shame to delete them. Many of the old questions asking for tools have *thousands* of views. This is no coincidence -- it's because newcomers and old users alike search on google for a tool or library to use and would appreciate the opinion of the internet with an upvote metric.

Comment: @Rapptz if the answers are no more than the name of the tool (which could be obsolete, superseded, etc.) and/or a dump of the wikipedia/product page entry, it should be deleted. Those users that view those highly upvoted *"examples"* will consider that it's right to ask here for tool recommendation. BTW, that's one of the highest reasons questions are being VtC'ed nowadays, after unclear/not enough debug information.