# Shall I delete an old recommendation question?

Tags: support, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120440/open-source-memory-mapped-hash-table-utilities-for-java

I asked this in the mists of time. More recently, I participated in closing it. I see a reopen vote, which leads me to want to delete it, but pushing the delete button brings me a stern warning.

Shall I ignore the warning and delete?

Comment: I don't think you *can* delete it since it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: @Mysticial is right- [You can't delete it both because it has an upvoted answer _and_ it has more than one answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) The warning is likely about question bans- Which I'm sure just at a glance that you're pretty well away from at this point. I think that's just an automatic warning that pops up whenever a user goes to delete their own question.

Comment: What's the language of the warning? I think users that have not contributed much to the site are warned against deletion because *they* are at risk of getting rate-limited or suspended if they do the post/delete/post/delete/post/delete dance too much. AFAIK, people in the several thousand of rep points would have to really work at it to trigger these penalties.

Comment: Note that the [reopen review outcome was to leave it closed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/9345285).

Comment: @Mysticial: as a 20k+ user, they can still *vote* to delete if not delete outright. I *think* that the OP is not prohibited from voting in that case.

Comment: Why delete it? Closing it as off topic probably, but it can still give useful pointers to users looking for something similar - don't you think?

Comment: What is funny now is that it is deleted but it has one reopen vote. I thought these would be cleaned after deletion.

Comment: @assylias: If it's off-topic then it's off-topic and shouldn't be here, regardless of how "useful" it may be. Something doesn't stay on SO just because it's "useful".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If it's off topic it should be closed. But deletion should only be used for stuff that adds no value (I believe), which I don't think is the case here. See for example: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286966/did-we-really-have-to-delete-this-80-vote-community-wiki-answer-after-three-year

Comment: Old recommendation questions are valueless, as they are obsolete almost immediately.

Comment: @assylias: That's the point. If it's off-topic then it has no value _here_. We don't close questions with a note "this is off-topic and you shouldn't have posted it, so we'll mark it as such but.. y'know.. wink wink nudge nudge it might _help_ somebody anyway so it'll remain accessible. just don't tell anyone". That is ultimately akin to saying off-topic posts are welcome. Of course we do keep the content available for a short time (as "on hold") so that it can be salvaged; to be honest I'm not sure why ancient off-topic posts aren't deleted after a while. They should be!

Answer (score 0):

**Let's check the Help Center.**

> Asking / [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)
>
> Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators. Over time, closed questions that are not useful as signpoints to other questions may also be removed, as well as questions which have no significant activity over a very long period after being asked.

- *extremely off topic:* this is very subjective, but I would argue that if it was on-topic once, it couldn't *extremly* off-topic now, it's just off-topic.
- *very low quality:* I assume this isn't the case, because else it would have been deleted a long time ago.
- *not useful as signpoints:* Recommendation questions are rarely referenced by other questions, therefore this probably can be applied.
- *no significant activity:* It reads like this applies to all question, but closed question don't have any significant activity per definition, therefore I assume this means question which had no activity ever (e.g. no good answers).

> Privileges / Moderator Tools / [When should I delete questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)
>
> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted.
>
> Before voting to delete, please check that there are no good answers; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!
>
> Also, be cautious when deleting questions closed as duplicates; they can serve as a signpost, directing users to useful answers on another question.

- *no lasting value:* This is extremely subjective and I wouldn't apply that as a delete reason. There was a [discussion about it on SO Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265528/what-questions-should-be-deleted), but there wasn't any accepted definition yet.
- *duplicates:* Doesn't apply to your case. In general duplicates should only be deleted if some of the other delete reasons match.

**Conclusion**

You may delete it because it's a closed question, which isn't useful as signpoint to other questions.

Ironically this delete reason wouldn't fit if it would have been reopened.

Comment: I didn't check Meta StackExchange. Maybe there is some clarification.